# How to model nested fixed-factor with GLMM

Tags: r, nested-data, lme4-nlme

I am a beginner on learning in GLMM and R, please forgive me if I am not making sense or asking something that is very basic.

I am trying to specify a nested fixed-factor in my GLMM model, but I don't seem to find the way to do it. I would really appreciate if someone can answer this question.

My experiment consists of four different species (A,B,C,D), and I have used all possible combinations of the four species as different treatments (composition, `Compo`, each `Compo` n = 4 in each `ExpRun`). `Compo` is therefore nested within `SPrich`, because `Compo` consisting only species A will only be possible under `SPrich` of 1, but not others. Therefore my data is not balanced under factor `SPrich`. For example:

```
SPrich  Compo(abbr.)
0       Control
1       A
1       B
1       C
1       D
2       AB
2       AC
2       AD
2       BC
2       BD
2       CD
3       ABC
...
4       ABCD
```

I am interested to know whether the species richness `SPrich` (five levels) and composition `Compo` (16 levels) has an effect on the response variable `WaterChlA`, which I measured on different `Day` from each of my experimental tanks `TankNo`. `WaterChlA` is not normally distributed, but more closely resemble a lognormal distribution, so gaussian link log is used. Samples from each `TankNo` are taken between `Day`, thus they are not independent.  I have conducted the experiment for three times, denoted in factor `ExpRun`. `TankNo` are denoted differently in all three `ExpRun` and therefore a nested random factor.

Here is a section of my data to demonstrate:

```
> str(Wetland)
'data.frame':   480 obs. of  31 variables:
$ TankNo    : Factor w/ 150 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ ExpRun    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Day       : Factor w/ 4 levels "1","8","15","22": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ SPrich    : Ord.factor w/ 5 levels "0"<"1"<"2"<"3"<..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ FxRich    : Ord.factor w/ 3 levels "0"<"1"<"2": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Compo     : Factor w/ 16 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
$ MIFI      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 ...
$ KAPU      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
$ DUME      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ POME      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ WaterChlA : num  8.33 1.99 35.56 17.49 22.04 ...
```

The question comes as my fixed-factor `Compo` should be nested within `SPrich` but it seems that it is more common to nest random factors in glmm, and I have not encounter on how to nest fixed-factors. I read in a Github post by Prof Bolker that specifying `A/B` in R actually equals to `1 + A + A:B`, but I wonder if writing that would be enough to specify the nestedness between `SPrich` and `Compo` (as below)? If not, **what should be the correct way to specify that `Compo` is nested within `SPrich`**?

I input the following into the model to run `glmer` with package `lme4`:

```
glmm1 <- glmer(WaterChlA ~ ExpRun + Day + SPrich/Compo + ExpRun*Day + ExpRun*SPrich + 
ExpRun*SPrich/Compo + Day*SPrich + Day*SPrich/Compo + (1|ExpRun/TankNo), data = Wetland, 
family = gaussian(link = "log"), na.action = na.exclude)
```

It said:

```
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 404 columns / coefficients
```

which is understandable because my fixed-factors are not full-rank but nested, so I am not too surprised if it has to drop the non-existing combinations of coefficients. However, it sort of demonstrates that the nestedness isn't really put into consideration by the model specified above(?). It also failed to converge:

```
Warning messages:
1: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.112084 (tol = 0.001, component 1)
```

I want to know whether the way I specify the nested `Compo` in `SPrich` is correct. I also wonder if GLMM is the most suitable way to analyze this type of data, or is there any other more suitable tools for this, perhaps GLM would be sufficient to analyze my data? I go for GLMM because there is quite a large variance among different Tanks and thus masking the effect of factors that are of interests, and treating `TankNo` as a random factor should help lower the influence.

Other than `SPrich`, I'm also interested to look at how functional richness `FxRich` affects the response, but `Compo` is nested within `FxRich` differently than within `SPrich` (say `Compo` A & B is same functional group and C & D is another, then `Compo` AB will be `SPrich` 2 and `FxRich` 1, while `Compo` AC will be `SPrich` 2 and `FxRich` 2, thus the nesting is quite different and complicated), which I think is more sensible to resolve later in another model that do not include `SPrich` or `Compo`. I wonder if this is reasonable? Perhaps this should go into another question thread and be discussed later...

Thank you all for you attention! Really appreciate any thoughts on the above!

Comment: by the time I finished answering I realized this should probably be on CrossValidated instead: voting to close/migrate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stream of consciousness:

- you might want to consider log-transforming the response (provided there are no zeros) rather than using the log link, i.e. `lmer(log(WaterChlA) ~ ...)` rather than `glmer(WaterChla ~ ..., family=gaussian(link="log"))`; I say this because log-transforming can take care of heteroscedasticity in the response (specifically a standard deviation approximately proportional to the expected mean value), which the log-link approach doesn't do (also, `lmer` tends to be a little bit faster and more stable than `glmer`)
- Nested fixed effects are indeed hard to specify in linear models (as opposed to ANOVA frameworks), where the underlying framework is explicitly trying to estimate parameters rather than just evaluate sums of squares/proportions of variance explained. If the parameters are not uniquely identifiable, then the model will end up dropping some terms. If your experimental design doesn't allow it, you simply *can't* estimate an interaction, which is necessary for nested terms. For example, you can't tell how the effect of `Compo=AB` varies among species richnesses, because `Compo=AB` only exists when species richness is 2.  You have a further problem: you can't even estimate the effect of species richness uniquely when `Compo` is in the model, because `Compo` is redundant with species richness (once you know the `Compo`, you know the species richness). Such redundancy is allowed in variance-decomposition approaches, or in Bayesian models, but not in linear models based on parameter estimation and models descended from them. You could make `Compo` a random effect (also a good modeling strategy because it has many levels, which will be expensive in terms of degrees of freedom); that would still allow you to quantify the effects.
- Since you have 480 data points, you should keep in mind the rule of thumb (e.g. from Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*) that you should not try to fit a model with more than *at most* n/10 = 48 parameters (that's extreme - typically the rule is stated as n/20, which would mean 24 parameters).  Because your predictors are all factors, trying to estimate interactions among them will rapidly make your model size blow up.
- `lme4` is known to give false-positive convergence warnings in some cases, but they look real in this case; I think the problem is that you have a model that is way overspecified/too complex ... see if stripping it down (as suggested below) helps.
- In general you shouldn't include a categorical variable (factor) as both a fixed effect and a random-effect grouping variable: that's a redundant model specification.

I would say a reasonable start for this model would be

```
lmer(log(WaterChlA) ~ Day*SPrich + (1|Compo) + (1|ExpRun/TankNo),
 data = Wetland, na.action = na.exclude)
```

although trying to estimate the interaction between `Day` and `SPrich` gives you 20 parameters, which is pushing it a bit.  You might consider whether you're willing to convert one or both of those factors to numeric (i.e. only looking for linear trends, or if you used `poly(Day,SPrich,degree=2)` that would give you quadratic terms with only 5 parameters ...)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and very informative reply! I guess with such a small number of data points, it is quite hard to come up with a realistic GLMM model. This is extremely useful and your answer points me to a new direction/approach. Thanks again!!!